# react-datepicker is not showing properly when i use it with ag-grid-react

Tags: ag-grid-react, react-datepicker

Added react-datepicker to the cell in ag-grid-react. I can only see the tip of the datepicker.The rest of the datepicker is covered behind next row. The next row overlaps the datepicker. Can someone please help with css class here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked for me -

```
.ag-cell {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.ag-row-focus {
    z-index: 1;
}

.ag-center-cols-viewport,
.ag-center-cols-clipper,
.ag-layout-normal {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)